# Windows path with a '$' at the end

Tags: c#, .net

```
 public static string QueuePrefix = @".\Private$\";
```

**what does the $ at the end of a string used for path traversel mean?** My google foo is not strong enough to find out.

Comment: It means the directory name ends with a dollar sign. You sometimes see _network share_ names that have special meaning that look like this, but it's just an ordinary character that may be used in a directory.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with C# or .NET.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the name of the variable - `QueuePrefix`, looks like MSMQ private queue path - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776346(WS.10).aspx

Otherwise, `$` is a valid character in file / directory name in Windows and it could just be that. Especially since it has `.\` in your case. But like others mentioned, it is used to to denote shares like `\\C$` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a MSMQ (Microsoft Message Queueing)-Path to me.
Private queues which are local to a system are prefixed with \Private$\ in MSMQ.

Comment: You meant "path" instead of "patch" I suppose?

Answer (score 4):

If it's a Windows system, the $ represents a hidden or administrative share. This is typically setup either by default ("C$" is the standard share for the C drive), or to obscure the shared folder so that it is not programmatically found or easy to access by unwanted users.

Answer (score 0):

A dollar sign doesn't have any special meaning in a path—it's interpreted as a normal character. It is often seen as part of a path for an administrative share, e.g., `\\C$\` for the C drive.